# How to extract MD5 data from a CSV file

Tags: encryption, csv, extract, md5

I have been sent a csv file that contains a list of emails that i'm told has MD5 encryption on it.
I want to be able to extract the email addresses from the file.

If i double-click it opens in Excel as what i assume is encrypted email addresses (looks like long hexadecimal)

Googling seems to point me in the direction of various pieces of softwaqre such as md5checker and md5summer but having downloaded them it's not clear to me how i use them to extract the data?

Any advice most welcome.

Comment: MD5 is not an encryption algorithm, it's a hashing algorithm. No data is "stored" in that file.

Comment: @Paul - What you want is not possible. There is an infinite number of possible MD5 collisions for those values. I could list two entirely different string values with the exact same MD5 hash. I won't do this because it would be difficult to find an example. Everything you need to know about MD5 is well documented including the high collision rate.  There are only 128-bits worth of possible values.  With today computing power you require 2056-bits to even be considered to be safe.

Comment: Ok thanks for the replies - i will get back to the person who sent it for more info on how he expects me to extract data from it.

Comment: The goal posts have moved on this.  What they now want is for me to apply md5 hashing to some email addresses i have and deduplicate them against the csv file they have sent. Any advice welcome.  Do i apply md5 to my csv file that the emails are in or to each individual email address within the file?   How would i then deduplicate?

Comment: Ok i assume i need to apply md5 to each email - is there a 3rd party tool that can help or will i need to do this within a database or code?

Answer (score 1):

md5 is a one way algorithm.

You will need month, years or centuries to brute force

Comment: Every possible MD5 value a string could have is known. It does not take centuries to brute force MD5 values more like minutes.  The problem of course is the fact the MD5 value of `String A` can also match `String B` because of collisions.  The only reason I will not issue a downvote to your answer ( lack of technical detail ) is the fact you mention MD5 is a one way hash algorithm.

Comment: note: md5 is no longer the preferred way to do it, due to security issues.. the second part of this answer isn't true.